# c++ casting base class to derived class mess

Tags: c++, class, casting, derived-class, base-class

If I were to create a base class called `base` and derived classes called `derived_1`, `derived_2` etc... I use a collection of instances of the base class, then when I retrieved an element and tried to use it I would find that C++ thinks it's type is that of the base class, probably because I retrieved it from a `std::vector` of base. Which is a problem when I want to use features that only exist for the specific derived class who's type I knew this object was when I put it into the vector.

So I cast the element into the type it is supposed to be and found this wouldn't work.

```
(derived_3)obj_to_be_fixed;
```

And remembered that it's a pointer thing. After some tweaking this now worked.

```
*((derived_3*)&obj_to_be_fixed);
```

Is this right or is there for example an `abc_cast()` function that does it with less mess?

edit:

I had to expand this into another question, the full solutions are shown there. [stackoverflow.com ... why-the-polymorphic-types-error-and-cleanup-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639703/why-the-polymorphic-types-error-and-cleanup-question)

Comment: Wait, is that a `std::vector< base >` or a `std::vector< base * >`? Because in the first case if you're storing objects of the derived class there's probably also some object slicing going on...

Comment: Ouch. In general you shouldn't do that because, as already said, you will have object slicing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), which actually reduces all your objects to instances of the base class; if you want to store objects of various derived classes of the same class hierarchy you have to use a `std::vector< base *>`; this will keep the objects intact, although you'll still get them as pointers to the base class (see @Peon the Great's answer to see how to deal with them).

Comment: Thanks for the object slicing info, such things not clear in C++. I will change my map to hold pointers instead.

Comment: `(derived_3&)obj_to_be_fixed` may appear to work, but it hasn't!

Comment: Got it Oli. Thanks. I'm going to use the std::vector<base*> solution now.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you store your objects in a `std::vector<base>` there is simply no way to go back to the derived class. This is because the derived part has been sliced of when storing it in an instance of base class (afterall your vector contains copies of your data, so it happily copies only the base part of your objectes), making the stored object a true instance of base class, instead of a derived class used as a base class.

If you want to store polymorphic objects in the vector make it a `std::vector<base*>` (or some kind of smartpointer to base, but not base itself) and use `dynamic_cast<derived_3*>` to cast it to the correct type (or `static_cast`, if its performance sensitive and you are confident enough that you are trying to cast to the correct type (in that case horrible things will happen if you are wrong, so beware)).

Comment: As far as I know casting is considered as a bad practice. So how polymorphic objects can be retrieved from the container without a bad practice?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a `vector` of `base` then all your instances are `base` instances and not derived instances.

If you try to insert a derived instance, the object will be *sliced*. Inserting into a `vector` always involves a *copy* and the target type is determined by the type of the object that the vector holds. A `vector` cannot hold objects of different types.

Comment: Apparently, as per other comments I must use std::vector<base*> to prevent slicing. Vectors can hold a mixture of types where as long as you know what type an element is you can get that element and do that type specific things to it. This is one way of doing it.

Comment: @alan2here: "Vectors can hold a mixture of types". This is simply not true, I'm afraid. If you use `std::vector< base* >` you have a vector of pointers. The pointers may point to objects of different types but the pointers themselves are all of the same type. And now, because your vector is a vector of pointers you know have to manage where the objects that those pointer point to are stored because the objects are not stored in the vector any more.

Comment: Thanks. I missworded it. I didn't know internally what was happening here. Good point about now having to manege more stuff.

Comment: @alan2here: Which is why we have boost::ptr_vector<base> which will manage the ptr objects for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you shall not need to do this.  A carefully designed class hierarchy can handle this by polymorphism (i.e. virtual functions).

If you really need to cast to the derived type, use `dynamic_cast` operator.

Comment: What you say is correct, but it doesn't address the most serious problem, i.e. the object slicing that's occurring.

Comment: I do assume pointers are used in vector when I see this question.  IMO throwing object instances into vector directly is a bad design.  Standard library allocators guarantee only and were tested only with primitives and Standard library types.  Anything other than those, pointers are better choices.

Comment: Well, the point in the question is that pointers are *not* used in the vector. ;) and also whu? Standard library containers are *designed* to store values, not pointers. Often, storing *pointers* in a container is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not even remotely possible. If the objects stored in your container have type `base`, then they are `base`, period. They are not `derived` objects, they will never become `derived` objects and they cannot be used as `derived` objects regardless of what you do.

Your cast through pointers is nothing than just a hack that reinterprets memory occupied by `base` object as `derived` object. This is totally meaningless and can only "work" by accident.