# why the polymorphic types error and cleanup question?

Tags: c++, types, stdmap, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class base {};
class derived1 : public base
{
    public:
        unsigned short n;
        derived1()
        {
            n = 2;
        }
};
class derived2 : public base {};

void main()
{
    // way 1
    {
        std::vector<derived1> a1;
        std::vector<derived2> a2;
        std::map<std::string, base*> b;
        a1.push_back(derived1());
        b["abc"] = &a1.at(0);
        std::cout<<(dynamic_cast<derived1*>(b.find("abc")->second))->n<<std::endl;
    }

    // way 2
    {
        std::map<std::string, base*> b;
        b["abc"] = new derived1();
        std::cout<<dynamic_cast<derived1*>(b.find("abc")->second)->n<<std::endl;
        delete dynamic_cast<derived1*>(b.find("abc")->second);
    }
}
```

The error is "'dynamic_cast' : 'base' is not a polymorphic type". What should be done to fix this? Is everything properly cleaned up in both way1 and way2?

Comment: `main` return type shouldn't be `void`.

Comment: General advice: do not store pointers to vector elements! As soon as reallocation occurs, these pointers get invalid! Only exception: if you can guarantee that no reallocation will occur any more and you do not remove elements such that a pointer would point beyond current vector size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make `Base` a polymorphic type, you need to give it at least one virtual function. The easiest in this case would be the destructor:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() { }
};
```

---

Regarding your question about cleanup:
Technically, there is some undefined behaviour in both ways, because the objects that the map refers to are destroyed before the pointers are removed from the map. This has the result that the map, when it is destructed, contains invalid pointers and that causes undefined behaviour.
For practical purposes, this does not cause any problems with any known compiler.

Otherwise, you are properly cleaning up everything.
But in way2, you can make a simplification. When `Base` has a virtual destructor, you can just do

```
delete b.find("abc")->second;
```

without the dynamic cast.

Comment: Thanks for the well written answer. I'm suprised and verry pleased that I can simplify the delete line in way2. So I can clean up objects on the other side of pointers where I don't know all the information about the type of the object that is being pointed to.

Comment: Dangling pointers do not cause Undefined Behavior unless they are dereferenced.  And a `map<std::string, base*>` does not dereference any of its `base*` pointers in its destructor or any other method.

Comment: @aschepler: Dangling pointers also cause UB (although with typically benign effects) if they are used in a context where an 'lvalue-to-rvalue conversion' occurs. Such a conversion occurs when a `map<X, Y>` destructs its contents.